# How ads to android application

Tags: android

I think about create some free applications on android but I would like to add some ads to make some money. How I can find good tutorial how I can add ads to my applications?

Comment: Just go to the ad providers.  They provide tutorials.

Comment: As @Simon has said, almost all ad providers typically include a sample / tutorial in their SDK's that you download. In the rare event they don't they always have them on their websites.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simon is right, it depends on the ad network. One of the simplest is Google's AdMob, which has its tutorial [here](https://developers.google.com/mobile-ads-sdk/).

Answer (score 1):

You should  contact ad providers like **`admob`**. chekck it . there are also more add provider available.